# Getting error when adding nested hashtable to array in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a nested hashtable with an array and I want to loop through the contents of another array and add that to the nested hashtable. I'm trying to build a Slack message block.

Here's the nested hashtable I want to add to:

```
$msgdata = @{
    blocks = @(
        @{
            type = 'section'
            text = @{
                type = 'mrkdwn'
                text = '*Services Being Used This Month*'
            }
        }
        @{
            type = 'divider'
        }      
    )
}

$rows = [ ['azure vm', 'centralus'], ['azure sql', 'eastus'], ['azure functions', 'centralus'], ['azure monitor', 'eastus2'] ]
$serviceitems = @()

foreach ($r in $rows) {
    $servicetext = "*{0}* - {1}" -f $r[1], $r[0] 
    $serviceitems += @{'type'='section'}
    $serviceitems += @{'text'= ''}
    $serviceitems.text.Add('type'='mrkdwn')
    $serviceitems.text.Add('text'=$servicetext)
    $serviceitems += @{'type'='divider'}
}

$msgdata.blocks += $serviceitems
```

The code is partially working. The hashtables @{'type'='section'} and @{'type'='divider'} get added successfully. Trying to add the nested hashtable of @{'text' = @{ 'type'='mrkdwn' 'text'=$servicetext }} fails with this error:

```
Line |
  24 |      $serviceitems.text.Add('type'='mrkdwn')
     |                                   ~
     | Missing ')' in method call.
```

I tried looking through various Powershell posts and couldn't find one that applies to my specific situation. I'm brand new to using hashtables in Powershell.

Comment: Wrong syntax for method invocation, you want: `$serviceitems.text.Add('type', 'mrkdwn')`

Comment: As an aside: `$rows = [ ['azure vm', 'centralus'] ...` is a syntax error too, please fix this statement to avoid a distraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementing mklement0's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204269/7571258), which solves the problem with your existing code, I suggest the following refactoring, using inline hashtables:

```sh
$serviceitems = foreach ($r in $rows) {
    @{
        type = 'section'
        text = @{
            type = 'mrkdwn'
            text = "*{0}* - {1}" -f $r[1], $r[0]
        }
    }
    @{
        type = 'divider'
    } 
}

$msgdata.blocks += $serviceitems
```

This looks much cleaner and thus easier to maintain in my opinion.

**Explanations:**

- `$serviceitems = foreach ...` captures all output (to the *success* stream) of the `foreach` loop in variable `$serviceitems`. PowerShell automatically creates an array from the output, which is more efficient than manually adding to an array using the `+=` operator. Using `+=` PowerShell has to **recreate** an array of the new size for each addition, because arrays are actually of fixed size. When PowerShell automatically creates an array, it uses a [more efficient data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0) internally.
- By writing out an inline hash table, without assigning it to a variable, PowerShell *implicitly* outputs the data, in effect adding it to the `$serviceitems` array.
- We output two hash tables per loop iteration, so PowerShells adds two array elements to `$serviceitems` per loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- This answer addresses your question *as asked*, specifically its syntax problems.
- For a superior solution that *bypasses* the original problems in favor of streamlined code, see [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204642/45375).

---

`$serviceitems.text.Add('type'='mrkdwn')` causes a syntax error.

***Generally* speaking**, *IF `$serviceitems.text` referred to a hashtable (dictionary)*, you need either:

- *method syntax* with distinct, `,`-separated arguments:

```sh
$serviceitems.text.Add('type', 'mrkdwn')
```

- or *index* syntax (which would quietly overwrite an existing entry, if present):

```sh
$serviceitems.text['type'] = 'mrkdwn'
```

PowerShell even lets you access hashtable (dictionary) entries with *member-access syntax* (dot notation):

```sh
$serviceitems.text.type = 'mrkdwn'
```

---

**In your specific case, additional considerations** come into play:

- You're accessing a hashtable *via an array*, instead of directly.
- The `text` entry you're trying to target isn't originally a nested hashtable, so you cannot call `.Add()` on it; instead, you must assign a *new* hashtable to it.

Therefore:

```sh
# Define an empty array
$serviceItems = @()

# "Extend" the array by adding a hashtable.
# Note: Except with small arrays, growing them with += 
#       should be avoided, because a *new* array must be allocated
#       every time.
$serviceItems += @{ text = '' }

# Refer to the hashtable via the array's last element (-1),
# and assign a nested hashtable to it.
$serviceItems[-1].text = @{ 'type' = 'mrkdwn' }

# Output the result.
$serviceItems
```